# Как анимировать пунктирную линию (SVG)

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, canvas, css-animation

Есть готовый файл, сохраненный в SVG.
Задача следующая, при наведение сделать его анимированным. 
Суть анимации: рисования элемента от начала до конца.
Я полазил по интернету и нашел подходящий пример анимации:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var canvas = Snap('.main-svg');
  var speed = 1000;
  var line_clients = canvas.path('M349.333,397.333c0,0,46,42.667,146-2.333 c17.917-8.063,79.666-31,87.333,65');
  line_clients.attr({
    class: "line-clients"
  });
  var group_line = canvas.group(line_clients);

  group_line.attr({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: '#fff',
    strokeWidth: 0
  });


  $.each([line_clients], function(index, value) {
    value.attr({
      strokeDasharray: value.getTotalLength(),
      strokeDashoffset: value.getTotalLength(),
      strokeWidth: 1,
      stroke: '#000'
    });

    value.animate({
        strokeDashoffset: 0
      },
      speed * 2,
      mina.easeinout
    );
  });
});
```

Только вот, когда открываешь мой SVG, я не ожидал, что там столько текста ради [такой линии](https://yadi.sk/d/7r6fT-zbrwoVU).
Я не прошу за себя сделать работу, но может кто-то пнет меня на нужный источник, а лучше пример.
Находил цент, какой с svg конвертирует в JS. Но я либо не разобрался, либо там нет возможности анимации.

Comment: а в чем вопрос-то? пример есть, svg есть. Что-то не работает или как?

Comment: @Grundy, в файл загляни - там жесть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну вроде ж руками с этим и не надо разбираться :)

Comment: @Grundy, есть набор абсолютно позиционированных штрихов произвольной формы в сомнительном порядке (первые 3 вообще принадлежат разным поворотам). Вопрос: как ты собираешься определить, где должен оказаться штрих при сдвиге на 1 шаг? Это наш мозг достраивает картину до пунктирной линии, в svg никакой информации об этом нет. А если и есть, то надо очень сильно постараться, чтобы её оттуда извлечь.

Comment: Можно анимировать и «это»: приблизительно нарисовать поверх свою кривую толстой линией цвета фона, закрывающей оригинал. И постепенно её скрывать по событию наведения мыши.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Рисовать в любом случае придётся. Эту линиую надо изобразить заново одним путём. Далее варианта два.

1. использовать оригинальный кривой и ужасный SVG. Поверх накрыть его своей линией цвета фона, толщины достаточной, чтобы закрыть полностью. Потом анимировать длину штриха и подобрать смещение так, чтобы кривая поверх «скрывалась», открывая пунктир под ней. Ниже эта техника подробнее.
2. если требуется рисовать сплошной линией – можно изобразить прорисовку одного длинного пути, меняя длину штриха (решение [отсюда](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)). Пришлось перерисовать путь, чтобы он стал одной кривой. Смотрите в полный экран, т.к. кривая крупная.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1490;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1490;
  animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="746px" height="482px" viewBox="0 0 746 482" enable-background="new 0 0 746 482" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20"/>
</svg>
```

---

Чтобы «рисовать» пунктиром можно сразу нарисовать весь путь пунктиром, а потом поверх закрыть этой же кривой цвета фона. И её не рисовать, а наоборот, скрывать задом наперёд той же техникой, как в первом коде. Пример с прорисовкой пунктирной окружности ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25455872/556876)):

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="1,6" stroke-width="1"  stroke="red" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="167" stroke-dasharray="1200,1200 " stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="white" fill="none">
       <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="1200" dur="4s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: `animate` - http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil - deprecated, будет удалена из браузеров. Ну либо подключать полифилл.

Comment: я предлагаю ТС использовать CSS3 свойство `animate` (в первом фрагменте кода).  Указанный вами deprecated "animate" – лишь в примере с окружностями, которые сразу рисуются. ТС, вероятно, захочет включать анимацию через JS, назначая элементу класс с CSS-свойством.

Answer (score 8):

### Решение SVG + Mask

Трудности с анимацией рисования с помощью пунктирной линии вызваны тем, что пунктирная линия заполняет **всю длину** линии или `path`.

Поэтому бесполезно пытаться повторить технику рисования, как это делается сплошной линией с помощью изменения `stroke-dashoffset` (отступа линии от начала) от максимума длины линии до нуля.

Линия заполнена полностью, поэтому она будет просто бежать:

```css
.path {
  
  stroke-dashoffset: 1490;
  animation: dash 12s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="746px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 746 500"  >
  
  <path class="path" fill="none"  stroke-dasharray="8 24"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20"/> 

</svg>
```

Решить данную проблему можно с помощью маски, которая сначала полностью повторяет и закрывает `path`, затем с помощью `stroke-dashoffset` постепенно сдвигается и открывает пунктирную линию, создавая иллюзию появления, рисования пунктирной линии.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_stroke.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 746 500"  >
  <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="0,1489" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20">
      <animate id="an_stroke" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="indefinite" dur="10s" values="0,1489;1489,0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  </mask>
</defs>
  <path class="path" fill="none" mask="url(#msk1)" stroke-dasharray="4 8" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20"/>  
 <text x="100" y="180" font-size="24" fill="dodgerblue" >Click me</text>

</svg>
```

- У атрибута `stroke-dasharray` может быть несколько пар параметров.
  Используя это свойство можно получить интересный эффекты:

`stroke-dasharray="4 8  36 4"`, где 4 - черта, 8 - пробел, 36 - черта, 4 - пробел

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_stroke.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 746 500"  >
  <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="0,1489" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20">
      <animate id="an_stroke" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="indefinite" dur="8s" values="0,1489;1489,0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  </mask>
</defs>
  <path class="path" fill="none" mask="url(#msk1)" stroke-dasharray="4 8  36 4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20"/>  
 <text x="100" y="180" font-size="24" fill="dodgerblue" >Click me</text>

</svg>
```

**Рисование из одной точки двумя прерывистыми линиями**

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_str.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="746px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 746 500"  >
  <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
     
      <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="0 745 0 745" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20">
      <animate id="an_str" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="10s" values="0 745 0 745; 0 0 1490 0" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
  </path>
  </mask>
</defs>
  <path class="path" fill="none" mask="url(#msk1)" stroke-dasharray="4 8" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M158,462.5h105.5c36.175,0,65.5-29.575,65.5-65.75
 s-29.263-65.375-65.438-65.375L84,331c-35.346,0-64-28.403-64-63.75c0-35.346,28.654-63.75,64-63.75h578
 c35.346,0,63.5-28.903,63.5-64.25V20"/> 
 
  <circle cx="135" cy="203" r="5" fill="red" /> 
  <text x="100" y="180" font-size="24" fill="dodgerblue" >Click me</text>

</svg>
```

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <circle class="maskCircle" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="-31.4" stroke-dasharray="0,62.8;0, 62.8">
    <!-- анимация рисования черточек -->  
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
     begin="background.mouseover"
     end="background.mouseout"
     dur="3s"
     values="0, 62.8 0, 62.8;0,0 125.6,0"
     fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="1"
     restart="whenNotActive" /> 
       <!-- анимация стирания черточек -->    
   <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   values="0,0 125.6,0;0, 62.8 0, 62.8"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle>
  </mask>
 
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
      <image x="-2.8" y="0" width="38%" height="38%" opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyUuX.jpg">
    <!-- анимация увеличения прозрачности изображения при наведении -->
    <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseover"
   dur="4s"
   values="0.05;1"
   fill="freeze" /> 
      <!-- анимация уменьшения прозрачности изображения при убирании курсора-->   
   <animate
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   to="0.05"
   fill="freeze" />  
   
   </image>
    </pattern>
   
</defs> 
    <g id="gr1">
    <circle id="background" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#image)" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
  stroke-dasharray="1.57" stroke-dashoffset="20"  mask="url(#msk1)">
  
  </circle>
 </g>  
 
  
</svg>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <circle class="maskCircle" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="125.6" stroke-dasharray="125.6">
    <!-- анимация рисования черточек -->  
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="background.mouseover"
     end="background.mouseout"
     dur="3s"
     values="125.6;0"
     fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="1" /> 
       <!-- анимация стирания черточек -->    
   <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   values="0;125.6"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1" />
  </circle>
  </mask>
 
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
      <image x="5" y="3" width="29%" height="29%" opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/acozx.jpg">
    <!-- анимация увеличения прозрачности изображения при наведении -->
    <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseover"
   dur="4s"
   values="0.05;1"
   fill="freeze" /> 
      <!-- анимация уменьшения прозрачности изображения при уводке курсора-->   
   <animate
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   to="0.05"
   fill="freeze" />  
   
   </image>
    </pattern>
   
</defs> 
    <g id="gr1">
    <circle id="background" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#image)" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
  stroke-dasharray="1.57" stroke-dashoffset="20"  mask="url(#msk1)">
  
  </circle>
 </g>  
 
  
</svg>
</div>
```

Крайний пример взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1038239/28748)

Comment: извините что не по теме скажите почему для удобства общения не вводят смайлики ?

Comment: @user354190 я даже на задумывался над этим.. мне вполне хватает скобок для выражения положительных и отрицательных эмоций

Comment: ясно спасибо за ответ и потраченное время

Comment: спасибо большое ...

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, оторвать руки тому, кто этот svg сделал, и переписать на пунктирную линию из прямых и дуг. В этом svg не линия - там каждый штришок сделан отдельным замкнутым контуром из кривых безье - всё это чудо объединено в один path. Думаю, ни у кого нет ни малейшего желания *это* анимировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее, должно получиться svg из следующего набора команд:

```
M ... v ... a ... h ... a ... h ... a ... h ...
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, внезапно))

Answer (score 4):

### Решение SVG + Mask + JS

Можно использовать пунктирную линию в качестве маски для анимированной линии.

```js
// Получить идентификатор элемента <path> и длину <path>
var myline = document.getElementById("myline");
var length = myline.getTotalLength();
circle = document.getElementById("circle");
// Начальная позиция анимации
myline.style.strokeDasharray = length;

// Скройте треугольник, смещая черту. Удалите эту линию, чтобы показать треугольник перед прокруткой
myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

// Найти процент прокрутки при прокрутке (используя свойства кросс-браузера) и сместить тире столько же, сколько и процент прокрутки
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // What % down is it?
  var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  // Длина для смещения тире
  var draw = length * scrollpercent;

  // тирайте рисунок (при прокрутке вверх)
  myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;

  //Получить точку
  endPoint = myline.getPointAtLength(draw);
  circle.setAttribute("cx", endPoint.x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", endPoint.y);

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#circle {
  fill: red;
}

#mySVG {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
}

.mask-style {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 7;
}
```

```html
<h2>Прокрутите это окно, чтобы нарисовать  путь..</h2>
<p>Scroll  назад, чтобы повернуть рисунок</p>

<svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 60 55" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width: 6%; padding-bottom: 42%; height: 1px; overflow: visible">
  <defs>
    <mask id="dash-mask">
      <path class="st0 mask-style" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 20 0 v 20 a 30 30 0 0 0 30 30 h 600 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -140 a 30 30 0 0 0 0 60 h 200 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -100 a 30 30 0 0 0 -30 30 v 20" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="circle" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
  <path id="myline" class="st0" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 20 0 v 20 a 30 30 0 0 0 30 30 h 600 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -140 a 30 30 0 0 0 0 60 h 200 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -100 a 30 30 0 0 0 -30 30 v 20" mask="url(#dash-mask)"/>
  Извините, ваш браузер не поддерживает SVG
</svg>
```

Comment: Привет Саша ..что такое endPoint.x ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Привет Имя переменной  `endPoint = myline.getPointAtLength(draw)`;