# SVG Анимация постепенного появления stroke-dasharray

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Спустя неоднократные попытки анимировать круг со свойством `stroke-dasharray`, придумал вариант вложенности circle в circle:

```css
svg {
 width: 300px;
}

svg circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke-width: 10;
 stroke: #000;
}

svg circle.default {
 opacity: .2;
 stroke-dasharray: 125.6;
}

svg circle.default.inner {
 opacity: .5;
 stroke-dashoffset: 125.6;
 animation: circle-default 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes circle-default {
 to {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 }
}

svg circle.dashed {
 stroke-dasharray: 1px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 <g>
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20"></circle>
  <circle class="default inner" cx="25" cy="25" r="20"></circle>
 </g>
 <g>
  <circle class="dashed" cx="80" cy="25" r="20"></circle>
 </g>
</svg>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q6oxu93h/)

Если слева анимирование происходит без каких-либо проблем, то объект справа не поддаётся такому же анимированию.

Идея заключается в помещении одного **circle** (который по частям) в чистый **circle** (в котором `dasharray` высчитывается как в первом). Тогда удастся анимировать внешний **circle** и сделать загрузку кружка по частям.

Хочется сделать анимацию разворачивания блока, но чтобы всё это было по частям (см. второй объект).

Comment: Попробую ответить на ваш вопрос. Вы не против, если моё решение будет немного не совпадать с вашим направлением?

Comment: Может вернутся ребята, в прошлых годах было очень много сильных отвечающих по SVG/.

Comment: Сделать вариант с анимацией в CSS? Правда не все сможет CSS, в частности он не понимает `stroke-dasharray` с несколькими парами значений

Comment: Это давний баг, который до сих пор не решен. На EnSO была дискуссия на эту тему Просто задайте вопрос здесь, поищем решения, мне самому интересно

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Когда вы разбиваете круг на равные сегменты с помощью `stroke-dasharray`, то невозможно 
анимировать их появление с заполнением круга с помощью `stroke-dashoffset`

Так как круг уже занят полностью. Можно поиграться с изменением величины и количества сегментов, то получатся интересные варианты, но это не то, что вы хотели получить:

```html
<svg width="360" height="360" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
    <circle class="background" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="8" />
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="8"
  stroke-dasharray="125.6" stroke-dashoffset="125.6">
  
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="7s" values="1.57, 124.03; 1.57,1.57" fill="freeze" /> 
   </circle>
 
</svg>
```

Поэтому можно решить данный вопрос с помощью маски, которая будет открывать круг, заранее разбитый на сегменты, создавая иллюзию заполнения:

Маска будет двигаться с помощью `stroke-dashoffset`, как у вас первая окружность.

```html
<svg width="360" height="360" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <circle class="maskCircle" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="125.6">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="4s" values="125.6;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  </mask>
</defs>
    <circle class="background" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="8" />
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="8"
  stroke-dasharray="1.57" stroke-dashoffset="20"  mask="url(#msk1)">
  
  </circle>
 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8):

Если поддержка браузерами позволяет, то можно так (при желании можно ещё поиграться с длиной штриха и анимацией `steps(5)`):

```css
html, body, svg {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.dashed {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 2.61;
  stroke-dashoffset: -1.275;
}

.hidden {
  fill: transparent;
}

g {
  animation: clip 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes clip {
  from { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 150% 50%, 150% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 150%, 50% 150%, 50% 50%, -50% 50%, -50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% -50%, 50% -50%, 50% 50%); }
   25% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 150% 50%, 50% 150%, 50% 50%, 50% 150%, 50% 150%, 50% 50%, -50% 50%, -50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% -50%, 50% -50%, 50% 50%); }
   50% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 150% 50%, 50% 150%, 50% 50%, 50% 150%, -50% 50%, 50% 50%, -50% 50%, -50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% -50%, 50% -50%, 50% 50%); }
   75% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 150% 50%, 50% 150%, 50% 50%, 50% 150%, -50% 50%, 50% 50%, -50% 50%, 50% -50%, 50% 50%, 50% -50%, 50% -50%, 50% 50%); }
    to { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 150% 50%, 50% 150%, 50% 50%, 50% 150%, -50% 50%, 50% 50%, -50% 50%, 50% -50%, 50% 50%, 50% -50%, 150% 50%, 50% 50%); }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-32 -32 64 64">
  <g>
    <circle r="25" class="hidden" />
    <circle r="20" class="dashed" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @MoloF, мне аж интересно стало, что считается обычным решением, а что необычным?)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Заценил, зачет (+)

Comment: @Qwertiy, тем что я о таком и не знал. Если про SVG animate, JS, я знал, то про это уж точно нет

Answer (score 7):

Таким вот способом можно получить нечто по сложнее окружности:

```js
let r = 80

function draw(t){
  let a = (t/500)%(Math.PI*7)
  let pts = [];
  for (let i=0; i<a; i+=0.01){
    pts.push([Math.cos(i)*(r-i*3), Math.sin(i)*(r-i*3)])
  }
  circle.setAttribute('d', 'M' + pts.join('L')) 
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

```css
body {margin:0;overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
 <path id=circle fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="18"
     stroke-dasharray="2"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: О, улиточка :))

Comment: Можно вас попросить посетить вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037944/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-perspective-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-svg?noredirect=1#comment1769523_1037944 ?

Comment: @MoloF пробовали поместить svg в разные div, а их уже подвигать по z?

Comment: Нет, думал есть более гуманные способы, если выхода нет и это проблема не моя а SVG то данный вариант вполне подходит для решения вопроса!

Comment: @MoloF ну в svg нет 3д трансформов, насколько мне известно

Comment: @MoloF нет полной уверенности что сработает, проверьте сначала =) я просто подумал что так должно, но не проверял =)

Answer (score 7):

### Концепт оформления галереи

Использовал эффект анимации   рисования сегментов из первого ответа.

При наведении курсора рисуется сегментный круг с анимацией появления изображения.
При уводе курсора сегментный круг сворачивается и прозрачность изображения уменьшается.

Подробности в комментариях к коду:

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <circle class="maskCircle" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="125.6" stroke-dasharray="125.6">
    <!-- анимация рисования черточек -->  
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="background.mouseover"
     end="background.mouseout"
     dur="3s"
     values="125.6;0"
     fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="1" /> 
       <!-- анимация стирания черточек -->    
   <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   values="0;125.6"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1" />
  </circle>
  </mask>
 
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
      <image x="5" y="3" width="29%" height="29%" opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/acozx.jpg">
    <!-- анимация увеличения прозрачности изображения при наведении -->
    <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseover"
   dur="4s"
   values="0.05;1"
   fill="freeze" /> 
      <!-- анимация уменьшения прозрачности изображения при уводке курсора-->   
   <animate
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   to="0.05"
   fill="freeze" />  
   
   </image>
    </pattern>
   
</defs> 
    <g id="gr1">
    <circle id="background" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#image)" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
  stroke-dasharray="1.57" stroke-dashoffset="20"  mask="url(#msk1)">
  
  </circle>
 </g>  
 
  
</svg>
</div>
```

**Пример анимации из одной точки 2 линиями**

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <circle class="maskCircle" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset="-31.4" stroke-dasharray="0,62.8;0, 62.8">
    <!-- анимация рисования черточек -->  
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
     begin="background.mouseover"
     end="background.mouseout"
     dur="3s"
     values="0, 62.8 0, 62.8;0,0 125.6,0"
     fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="1"
     restart="whenNotActive" /> 
       <!-- анимация стирания черточек -->    
   <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   values="0,0 125.6,0;0, 62.8 0, 62.8"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle>
  </mask>
 
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
      <image x="-2.8" y="0" width="38%" height="38%" opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyUuX.jpg">
    <!-- анимация увеличения прозрачности изображения при наведении -->
    <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseover"
   dur="4s"
   values="0.05;1"
   fill="freeze" /> 
      <!-- анимация уменьшения прозрачности изображения при убирании курсора-->   
   <animate
      attributeName="opacity"
   begin="background.mouseout"
   dur="1s"
   to="0.05"
   fill="freeze" />  
   
   </image>
    </pattern>
   
</defs> 
    <g id="gr1">
    <circle id="background" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#image)" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
  stroke-dasharray="1.57" stroke-dashoffset="20"  mask="url(#msk1)">
  
  </circle>
 </g>  
 
  
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

В целом что-то такое всегда можно изобразить при помощи js математики и команды arc:

```js
let r = 80

function draw(t){
  let a = (t/1000)%(Math.PI*2)
  let x = Math.cos(a)*r;
  let y = Math.sin(a)*r;
  let largeArc = a > Math.PI ? 1 : 0;
  circle.setAttribute('d', `M${r},0A${r},${r},0,${largeArc},1,${x},${y}`) 
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

```css
body {margin:0;overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
 <path id=circle fill="none"stroke="black" stroke-width="18" stroke-dasharray="2"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Интересно (тоже плюс), но в нижней части окружности шевеление довольно заметно - как будто волна туда-обратно бегает, особенно в маленьком размере. Кстати, в верхней - тоже, но нижнюю больше заметно - возможно она просто дольше на экране.

Comment: Эм.. А как ты смог полный круг через одну дугу сделать? Вроде ж две надо, потому что точки не могут совпадать?

Comment: @Qwertiy так они и не совпадут, из-за точности синусов итд, да и если совпадет то на долю секунды - а потом по-новой

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, по идее в момент когда отрисован полный круг, у него начальная и конечная точка должны совпадать. А если они не совпадают просто из-за точности, то вполне может получиться, что они не совпадают в другую сторону и вместо полного оборота отрисуется почти нулевой. Или я неправ?

Comment: @Qwertiy прав, это начало следующего оборота, в общем этого не видно =)

Comment: Да, надо извлекать плюшки из того, что оно крутится непрерывно и не требуется останавливаться на полном круге)))

Comment: @Qwertiy да и полный круг я рисую так `M100,0A100,100,0,1,0,100.01,0`, кстати не исключено что "ползти" не будет если нарисовать по точкам а не через arc, как в ответе рядом