# Не работает perspective (перспектива) на объекте SVG

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Создал небольшую анимацию SVG объекта, но при самой анимации всё выглядит будто сплюснутый бутерброд.

Приложу [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zcjyvgt4/)

```css
.container {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .object {
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 perspective: 2000px;
 position: relative;
 animation: object-rotate 3s infinite;
 transform: rotate3d(0.2, 1, 0, -40deg) translate;
}

@keyframes object-rotate {
 0% {
  transform: rotate3d(0.2, 0.2, 0, 45deg);
 }

 25% {
  transform: rotate3d(0.2, 1, 0, 45deg);
 }

 50% {
  transform: rotate3d(0.2, 0.2, 0, -45deg);
 }

 75% {
  transform: rotate3d(0.2, 0.2, 0, -45deg);
 }

 100% {
  transform: rotate3d(0.2, 0.2, 0, 45deg);
 }
}

.container svg {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}

.container svg circle {
 fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-width: 5;
}

.container span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transform: translateZ(50px);
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
}

.container .logo {
 animation: object-rotate 5s infinite;
}

.container .logo .background {
 fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .logo .stroke path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 stroke-width: 5;
 stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.container .logo .outline path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #e74c3c;
 stroke-width: 20;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 stroke-miterlimit: 10;
 animation: logo-outline-path 3s infinite;
}

.container .logo .outline path:nth-child(1) {
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container .logo .outline path:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

.container .logo .outline path:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes logo-outline-path {
 0% {
  stroke-width: 20;
 }

 50% {
  stroke-width: 10;
 }

 100% {
  stroke-width: 20;
 }
}

.container .logo .dots circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #e74c3c;
 stroke-width: 20;
 stroke-miterlimit: 10;
 animation: logo-dots 3s infinite;
}

.container .logo .dots circle:nth-child(1) {
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container .logo .dots circle:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

.container .logo .dots circle:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes logo-dots {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 50% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.container .logo .center .background {
 opacity: 0.1;
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000000;
 stroke-width: 3;
 stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.container .logo .center .line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #e74c3c;
 stroke-width: 3;
 stroke-miterlimit: 10;
 stroke-dasharray: 100%;
 animation: logo-circle-line 5s infinite;
 transform-origin: center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
}

@keyframes logo-circle-line {
 from {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
 }

 to {
  transform: rotateZ(359deg);
 }
}

.container .logo .center .inner {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #e74c3c;
 stroke-width: 75;
 stroke-miterlimit: 100;
 stroke-dasharray: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
}

.container .logo .center .inner .inner {
 stroke-width: 100;
}

.container .logo .center .inner.active {
 opacity: 1;
 stroke: #e74c3c;
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.container .logo .center polyline {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #e74c3c;
 stroke-width: 50;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 stroke-miterlimit: 1;
}
```

```html
<h4>Данный вариант будет работать</h4>
<div class="container">
 <div class="object">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
  </svg>
  <span>Text</span>
 </div>
</div>
<h4>Данный вариант не будет работать</h4>
<div class="container">
 <div class="object">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo">
     <path class="background" d="M798.8,2.5h591.81c82.46,0,108.07,44.63,144.15,107.12s82.63,142.83,41.4,214.25L1280.25,836.4l-295.91,512.52 c-41.23,71.42-113.39,71.47-185.54,71.47s-144.31-0.06-185.54-71.47L317.35,836.4L21.44,323.87c-40.74-70.56-8.2-121.84,26.71-184 C83.9,76.21,123.53,2.5,206.98,2.5H798.8z"/>
     <g class="stroke">
      <path class="bottom" d="M798.1,1055.45c-116.26,0-222.91-41.14-306.2-109.65l154.98,268.43 c33.76,58.47,92.83,65.83,151.91,65.83c59.08,0,118.15-7.36,151.91-65.83l156.28-270.68 C1023.3,1013.4,915.62,1055.45,798.1,1055.45z"/>
      <path class="top-left" d="M162.36,375.01l159.85,276.87c-4.21-25.63-6.44-51.93-6.44-78.76 c0-217.16,143.52-400.78,340.87-461.23H314.27c-69.44,0-99.89,51.03-128.77,104.49C158.22,266.88,129.57,318.21,162.36,375.01z"/>
      <path class="top-right" d="M1280.43,573.12c0,28-2.42,55.43-6.99,82.12l161.8-280.24 c33.16-57.43,8.44-100.68-19.69-151.44c-29.14-52.59-63.51-111.67-132.22-111.67H939.55 C1136.91,172.35,1280.43,355.97,1280.43,573.12z"/>
     </g>
     <g class="outline">
      <path class="top-left" d="M314.27,111.89c-69.44,0-99.89,51.03-128.77,104.49c-27.28,50.49-55.93,101.82-23.13,158.62"/>
      <path class="bottom" d="M647.53,1214.23c33.76,58.47,92.83,65.83,151.91,65.83c59.08,0,118.15-7.36,151.91-65.83"/>
      <path class="top-right" d="M1435.23,375.01c33.16-57.43,8.44-100.68-19.69-151.44 c-29.14-52.59-63.51-111.67-132.22-111.67"/>
     </g>
     <g class="dots">
      <circle class="top" cx="797.4" cy="111.89" r="10"/>
      <circle class="bottom-left" cx="402.17" cy="811.45" r="10"/>
      <circle class="bottom-right" cx="1193.4" cy="811.45" r="10"/>
     </g>
     <g class="center">
      <circle class="background"  cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="415"/>
      <circle class="line"  cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="415"/>
      <circle class="inner" cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="325"/>
      <circle class="inner active" cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="325"/>
      <polyline points="964.94,482.14 803.78,776.36 629.86,489.5"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
 </div>
</div>
```

Проблема заключается как раз в плоскости самого объекта. Буквально вырвал из проекта логотип и анимировал немного. Вопрос касается только этого сплюснутого бутерброда, перспектива на SVG не действует как бы я не пытался.

@Alexandr_TT , я создал отдельно тему.

На Jsfiddle стили более читабильны, здесь я просто воспользовался онлайн компилятором и всё перенёс.

upd: Да, я пробовал каждому элементу добавлять абсолютное позицирование, пробовал менять translateZ и ещё много других извращений, с места относительно Z он не сдвинулся. По X,Y всё тянется, но по Z - нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23230218/4928642

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVG-Transforms-20090320/#perspective-property

Answer (score 3):

```css
.logo {
  animation: logo-wrapper-transform 5s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.logo svg {
  display: block;
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(10px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateZ(20px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateZ(30px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateZ(40px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(6) {
  transform: translateZ(60px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(7) {
  transform: translateZ(70px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(8) {
  transform: translateZ(80px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(9) {
  transform: translateZ(90px);
}
.logo svg:not(:first-child):nth-child(10) {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}
@keyframes logo-wrapper-transform {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0.2, 1, 0, 30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0.2, 1, 0, -30deg);
  }
}
.logo .logo-background path {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.logo .logo-stroke path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.logo .logo-outline path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  animation: logo-outline-path 3s infinite;
}
.logo .logo-outline path:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.logo .logo-outline path:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.logo .logo-outline path:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes logo-outline-path {
  0% {
    stroke-width: 20;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-width: 10;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-width: 20;
  }
}
.logo .logo-dots circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  animation: logo-dots 3s infinite;
}
.logo .logo-dots circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.logo .logo-dots circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.logo .logo-dots circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes logo-dots {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.logo .logo-center-background .wrapper {
  opacity: 0.1;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.logo .logo-center-background .inner {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  animation: logo-circle-line 5s infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
@keyframes logo-circle-line {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(359deg);
  }
}
.logo .logo-center-inner .inner {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  stroke-width: 75;
  stroke-miterlimit: 100;
  stroke-dasharray: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.logo .logo-center-inner .inner .inner {
  stroke-width: 100;
}
.logo .logo-center-inner .inner.active {
  opacity: 1;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.logo .logo-center-inner polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  stroke-width: 50;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo-background">
  <path d="M798.8,2.5h591.81c82.46,0,108.07,44.63,144.15,107.12s82.63,142.83,41.4,214.25L1280.25,836.4l-295.91,512.52 c-41.23,71.42-113.39,71.47-185.54,71.47s-144.31-0.06-185.54-71.47L317.35,836.4L21.44,323.87c-40.74-70.56-8.2-121.84,26.71-184 C83.9,76.21,123.53,2.5,206.98,2.5H798.8z"/>
 </svg>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo-stroke">
  <path class="bottom" d="M798.1,1055.45c-116.26,0-222.91-41.14-306.2-109.65l154.98,268.43 c33.76,58.47,92.83,65.83,151.91,65.83c59.08,0,118.15-7.36,151.91-65.83l156.28-270.68 C1023.3,1013.4,915.62,1055.45,798.1,1055.45z"/>
  <path class="top-left" d="M162.36,375.01l159.85,276.87c-4.21-25.63-6.44-51.93-6.44-78.76 c0-217.16,143.52-400.78,340.87-461.23H314.27c-69.44,0-99.89,51.03-128.77,104.49C158.22,266.88,129.57,318.21,162.36,375.01z"/>
  <path class="top-right" d="M1280.43,573.12c0,28-2.42,55.43-6.99,82.12l161.8-280.24 c33.16-57.43,8.44-100.68-19.69-151.44c-29.14-52.59-63.51-111.67-132.22-111.67H939.55 C1136.91,172.35,1280.43,355.97,1280.43,573.12z"/>
 </svg>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo-outline">
  <path d="M314.27,111.89c-69.44,0-99.89,51.03-128.77,104.49c-27.28,50.49-55.93,101.82-23.13,158.62"/>
  <path d="M647.53,1214.23c33.76,58.47,92.83,65.83,151.91,65.83c59.08,0,118.15-7.36,151.91-65.83"/>
  <path d="M1435.23,375.01c33.16-57.43,8.44-100.68-19.69-151.44 c-29.14-52.59-63.51-111.67-132.22-111.67"/>
 </svg>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo-dots">
  <circle cx="797.4" cy="111.89" r="10"/>
  <circle cx="402.17" cy="811.45" r="10"/>
  <circle cx="1193.4" cy="811.45" r="10"/>
 </svg>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo-center-background">
  <circle class="wrapper"  cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="415"/>
  <circle class="inner"  cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="415"/>
 </svg>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1594.8 1422.89" class="logo-center-inner">
  <circle class="inner" cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="325"/>
  <circle class="inner" cx="797.4" cy="573.45" r="325">
   <circle class="active" cx="0" cy="0" r="325"></circle>
  </circle>
  <polyline points="964.94,482.14 803.78,776.36 629.86,489.5"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Собственно смог достичь необходимого эффекта с помощью совета **[@Stranger in the Q (/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q)**

Разделил объекты на разные svg, поместил их в контейнер и выдвинул. Так же приложу код с [Jsfiddle где в стилях используется SASS](https://jsfiddle.net/e56f7aj8/)

Comment: Это то, что вы хотели получить? Или как-то по другому хотелось, пока только локальная победа? :) (+)

Comment: Неплохо вышло, рад что помог

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , конечно же это не вся анимация и перспектива меняется, здесь я выложил код чтобы было видно что "выпирает".